# Marker move According to Route MapBox

Tags: ios, swift4, mapbox

I have two annotations. There is an image on annotation. I want the image head toward route in MapBox.

Here is what I have tried:

```
func drawAnnoation (orgin :CLLocationCoordinate2D ,destination :CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        if annotation == nil {
         annotation = CameraAnnotation(coordinate: orgin, title: "SOURCE", subtitle: "D", image:"selfImage" )
            let source = orgin
        annotation.coordinate = source
        annotation.title = "ddd"

            map.setCenter(orgin, zoomLevel: 18, animated: false)
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
                // Here Core Animation calls MapBox using an implicit animation.
                self.annotation.coordinate = orgin

            })
        }
        if annotations == nil {
        let annotations = NoteAnnotation(coordinate: destination, title: "DESTINATION", subtitle: "E", image: "car")
        let sources = destination
        annotations.coordinate = sources
        annotations.title = "d"
        map.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }
    }



func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is CameraAnnotation || annotation is NoteAnnotation else {
            return nil
        }
        if annotation is CameraAnnotation {

            return dview
        } else {

            return sdview
        }
   }
```

Please help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you mean that it looks like Uber ...when route is moving then simultaneously your annotation should be processed.

i suppose that you need to use Socket for iOS in which you can get lat and long continoulsy from socket and then set the lat and long with annotation .

let source = CLLocation(latitude: Socket_latitiude_value, longitude: Socket_longitude_value)

if annotations == nil {
        let annotations = NoteAnnotation(coordinate: sources , title: "DESTINATION", subtitle: "E", image: "car")
        annotations.coordinate = sources
        annotations.title = "d"
        map.addAnnotation(annotations)
        }